# How to store values returned from db when method is asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, node-postgres

I am new to node/js and I was wondering what I should do to fix my DB call. At the moment the call goes to return all data from my Postgres DB but when I try to store it the values are not yet returned. How should I go about structuring my code so I can wait until the values get stored so that when that info is passed to the next variable it's available? If you look below, you can see that the `returnedOrders` field will have the `undefined` value since the value from the db is still being fetched before it gets filled.

```
function insertOrder() {
     dbConnector.connectToDB();
     const returnedOrders =  await dbConnector.retrieveAllOrders();
     console.log("The returned orders" , returnedOrders);
}

function connectToDB() {
    conn.connect().then((success, error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(`There was an error connecting because: ${error}`);
        }else {
            console.log(`Successfully connected to the database: ${success}`);
        }
    });
}


function retrieveAllOrders(){
    const query = `SELECT * from food.pizza`;
        conn.query(query).then((results, error) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(`There was an error due to: ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            console.log("Successfully connected. Running first query");
            console.log(`Results are: ${JSON.stringify(results.rows[0], null , 2)}}`)
            conn.end();
            return results;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Unable to retrieve query due to: ${error.message}`)
        })

}
```

This is the output from my terminal. Here you can see the order things happen in

```
node app.js 
The returned orders undefined
Successfully connected to the database: [object Object]
Successfully connected. Running first query
Results are: { Here will be the results from the database. }
```

Comment: callbacks and/or promises

Comment: `return conn.query(query)` -- `return conn.connect().then(` -- `async function insertOrder()`

Comment: Hey Kevin I get this `The returned orders undefined` still in the output.

Comment: i don't understand this part of your code: `dbConnector.retrieveAllOrders` how does `retrieveAllOrders`, defined below, become a property of `dbConnector`?

Comment: This method will retrieve all the data from the db. Then I wanted to store that value into a variable. Then I would pass that variable into another method that parses that data and saves the necessary info into another service.

Comment: What i mean is, why is this line: `const returnedOrders =  await dbConnector.retrieveAllOrders();` not `const returnedOrders =  await retrieveAllOrders();`, i don't see where you are adding `retrieveAllOrders` to `dbConnector`

Comment: I would expect it to throw an error as written

Comment: It's part of the same class. So when I import the class itself, that method is part of the class. Which is why I do the `dbConnector.retrieveAllOrders();`

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was missing. given the changes in my second comment, the order of your logs in the console should have changed, did they?

Comment: yes the order has changed. But I still get back undefined for the results.

Comment: Sounds like you’re still missing a return somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232978/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-kevin-b).